Question regarding 301 redirects and rankings transfer time frame
A few months ago i upgraded my free wordpress site to a paid plan.
The free site is redirecting to the new paid domain now.
I'm still waiting on the rankings to be transferred to the new domain. My paid site is now in google search console. Someone suggested creating a new google account, adding my free site to gsc and saying my site has moved to the new domain to speed things up.
Does anyone know if: a> it will make a difference to how long it will take to transfer and b> why they would suggest making a new google account for that?

I assume they just meant new Google Search Console property rather than new account.  I can think of no reason to create a new Google account.
Can you clarify what you mean by "rankings to be transferred" - is your new domain now indexed, or is the old one still showing in the SERPs?

The new domain is indexed. Whether or not it's fully indexed, I'm not sure as I'm still waiting on gsc to update. What i mean is that the new domain is hardly getting any traffic compared to how much the free site was getting. I guess I'm just wondering if doing this would speed up the process of google transfering that domain age and inbound links to the new site.

Actually my bad. The old site is still indexed

If you haven't done so, I suggest adding a sitemap.xml to the new domain, canonical to the pages in it, and making sure all URLs in the old domain redirect (301) to the new domain. This will help Google index pages in the new domain faster, and remove the pages from the old domain from the search results.

First question, do I understand correctly that you currently have both domains added in GSC? And then you used the change of address feature?
Make sure that your 301 redirects are set up correctly and that all pages from the old site are redirecting to the new paid domain.

So wordpress does some site wide 301. I had both in there but then one day the free site had a message stating it's unverified now. I have 2 sites. One i didn't do the change of address and one i did. It's still saying it's moving to the new address.

Are there any bugs in the GSC?

I will check on this

If you properly do 301 redirects from your old sites to the new site then you have to do nothing. Make sure each of your old site links redirects to the new site links. You have to update your new site map in Webmaster. Now, You should focus on publishing new content on the new site regularly. Within a few weeks, your new site's URLs will start indexing.

Would you know why the old free site is still indexed? This was done months ago.

Yes, sometimes the old sites are indexed because of having a good reputation in the past or still getting backlinks from reputed sites.
